# Dont change resolved value in .then()

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have 2 function that return promises, `P1` and `P2`. First I want to wait until `P1()` is fulfilled, then I want to execute `P2` and when `P2()` is fulfilled I want to do something with the value `P1()` resolved to. It is easy to do using `async/await` like this:

```
const result = await P1()
await P2()
doSomething(result)
```

but I cant use `async/await`. Using promises I can do it like this:

```
P1().then((result) => P2().then(() => result)).then((result) => doSomething(result))
```

but is there any prettier way to do it (without nested `then`s)?

Comment: Nesting `then` is just a fine solution, but you can simplify to `P1().then(result  => P2().then(() => doSomething(result)))`

Answer (score 4):

You could use Promise.all like this, it waits until all promises have been resolved (or the first rejection).

```
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(result => { 
  doSomething(result);
});
```

or the more terse:

```
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(result => doSomething(result));
```

Comment: or more terse: `Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(doSomething)`

Comment: haha yer or that :-D

Comment: Ahh I will need to update my question. `P1` and `P2` should be functions that return promises. I just wanted to make it simpler and I didn't realize it is so different :) The point is, if `P2` is a function, I want to execute it **after** `P1()` is fulfilled

Comment: In that case, what you had originally is the way to go, there is no other way I am aware of, so this maybe? Also depends on if you want to pass the result from P1? It's a little shorter...

P1().then(() => P2().then(result => doSomething(result)));

Answer (score 1):

It seems that P1 and P2 are independent, as you are not using the value of P1 to start the call of P2. If that's the case you can use `.all()` method to run those 2 promises in parallel, and then do something with their results.

```
Promise.all([P1, P2]).then(([ P1Result, P2Result ]) => {
  doSomething(P1Result, P2Result);
});
```

However if P2 does depends on P1, the nested `.then()` would be the way to go. I've created a tiny module to ease the calls of promises in series, where it is even possible to mix sync and async methods on the same pipeline. Take a look and see if that can help you on getting rid of writing the nested `.then()` methods: https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/pipe-functions